# having node-stringprep with node 4.x

Tags: c, node.js, linux

I have this `package.json` no a `centos` box.

```
$cat package.json 
{
  "name": "module-name",
  "version": "10.3.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-stringprep": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

with node `0.12.6` i can run `npm install` with no problem.  I have to run it now due to circumstances under node `4.x` (I also tried with `node-stringprep 0.8.0` i tried with a few and with all of them i get error i understand that node-stringprep says: `"node": ">=0.8 <=0.12"` i'm still trying to have my server run while its dependant on it on node 4.x.

error specifically for example `4.4.4`:

```
# npm install
npm WARN package.json module-name@10.3.1 No description
npm WARN package.json module-name@10.3.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json module-name@10.3.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json module-name@10.3.1 No license field.
npm WARN engine node-stringprep@0.7.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12"} (current: {"node":"4.4.4","npm":"2.15.1"})
-
> node-stringprep@0.7.3 install /root/tmp/test/node_modules/node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory `/root/tmp/test/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_stringprep/node-stringprep.o
In file included from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of 'template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)'
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: 'template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)' previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: 'node::smalloc' has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'callback'
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)':
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: 'callback' was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: 'hint' was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)':
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded 'New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)' is ambiguous
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:25:0,
                 from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.4/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.4/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' to 'node::encoding'
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.4/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.4/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const char*' to 'char*'
In file included from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)':
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert 'node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))' from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                                                             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)':
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:12: error: 'Use' is not a member of 'node::Buffer'
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_stringprep/node-stringprep.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/tmp/test/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/tmp/test/node_modules/node-stringprep
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-stringprep@0.7.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-stringprep@0.7.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-stringprep package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-stringprep
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-stringprep
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

anyone knows if there is a way for me to resolve it?